# custom commands in external xaml files loaded with xaml reader

Tags: xaml, command, xml-namespaces

I am lost with custom commands and the bindings.
I have a main XAML-File, which is just a container.

```
<Window x:Class="MyNS.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"         
        xmlns:a="clr-namespace:MyNS.Actions"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding 
                    Command="{x:Static a:OpenWindow.Cmd}"                
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteActionAsCommand" 
                    Executed="ExecuteActionAsCommand" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Grid Name="ContentPanel">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and now I want to load during runtime an additional XAML-file with the XAML Reader. All in all it works fine. But now I have a Button there with a custom command and there I am lost.
The additional file looks like this:

```
<StackPanel             
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            xmlns:a="clr-namespace:MyNS.Actions">

      <Button Content="Show Properties" Grid.Row="1" 
              Command="{x:Static a:OpenWindow.Cmd}" 
              CommandParameter="startup_screen2" />
</StackPanel>
```

Now the Problem is that the XAML Reader is not able to solve the "x:Static".

My question is if anybody has an idea how I can define my custom command that I can call it in my additional XAML-file.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the assembly name to the namespace declaration of xmlns:a in your loose XAML:

```
xmlns:a="clr-namespace:MyNS.Actions";assembly=YourAssemblyName
```

Now XamlReader shoud find your custom command.